# Find file name from string in batch program

Tags: dos, batch-file

I am new to batch programming. I want to find filename and its extension from a String. I see answers where path is in for variable e.g.

```
    for /f %%a in ('dir /B') do (
    file_name= %%~nxa
    )
```

But following code does not work.

```
    stringvar="c:/folder1/folder2/abc.txt"
    file_name=%%~nxstringvar
```

I tried many permutation and combination with stringvar and %% and ~nx in expression. But I did not get filename.

Please consider below code to understand the need.

```
    stringvar="c:/folder1/folder2/abc.txt"
    filename=getFileName(stringvar)
```

Any answer or suggestion is most welcome. Thankig you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Special var parameters are only for special vars (%0,%1, etc) and for "FOR" vars, so first you need to call anything passing the variable like an argument, or to do a FOR:

```
@Echo OFF
SET "stringvar=c:\folder1\folder2\abc.txt"
Call :sub "%stringvar%"
Pause&Exit

:sub
Echo FILENAME: "%~nx1"
GOTO:EOF
```

**EDIT**: don't use "/" slashes, you are on Windows, and don't enclose the var like you are doing, see my example.

Comment: +1, but I prefer to use FOR variables because FOR is significantly faster than CALL:  `for %%F in ("%stringVar%") do set "fileName=%%~nxF"`